# CURSOR function equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, cursor, batch-processing

I would like to ask regarding a code equivalent in SQL Server

I'm working on a project wherein we will be converting unix batches to windows batches due to database migration. Since I'm on shell scripts and oracle stuffs, I'm having a hard time working on windows side.

My question is about the CURSOR that oracle sql uses.

Can someone help me convert the following sample query below

`sampleanimal.sql`:

```
declare cursor getGM is
select dog as d, cat as c, fish as f
  from animals

begin
  for dr in getGM loop

    UPDATE zoo
      SET dogs = dr.d
          cats = dr.c
          fishes = dr.f
      ;

  end loop;
end;
/

commit;

quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Really, you not need to use cursor in this case. Try something like this -

```
UPDATE z
SET 
      dogs = a.dog
    , cats = a.cat
    , fishes = a.fish
FROM zoo z
JOIN animals a ON z.id = a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be more efficient or easy way, I just wrote without test

```
DECLARE @d nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @c nvarchar(10);
DECLARE @f nvarchar(10);

DECLARE getGM CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
select dog as d, cat as c, fish as f from animals

OPEN getGM
FETCH NEXT FROM getGM INTO @d, @c, @f

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
UPDATE zoo
      SET dogs = @d
          cats = @c
          fishes = @f

FETCH NEXT FROM getGM INTO @d, @c, @f
End

CLOSE getGM
DEALLOCATE getGM
```

you can check examples from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx)